# React Material-UI Select is not reflecting the change

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui, rerender

I have a list of objects with product data:

```
[
    {
        barcode: "21METAHTAM29RM"
        discount: 0
        price: "359990"
        qty: "2"
        size: "m"
    },
    {
        barcode: "21METAHTAM29RL"
        discount: 0
        price: "359990"
        qty: "1"
        size: "l"
    },
    ...
]
```

I use `size` field to show the option from which you can select the product size:

```
...

const [prodDetails, setProdDetails] = useState({});

const handleChange = (event) => {
    var specificProd = JSON.parse(event.target.value)
    setProdDetails(specificProd)
};

...

<FormControl className={classes.sizes}>
    <InputLabel htmlFor='size-select'>SIZE</InputLabel>
    <Select
        id='size-select'
        native
        value={prodDetails.size}
        onChange={handleChange}
    >
       {newProd[0].sizepricesdiscountqty.map((item, i)=>{
           if(parseInt(item.qty) > 0){
               return <option key={i} value={JSON.stringify(item)}>
                   {item.size.toUpperCase()}
               </option>
           } else {
               return <option disabled key={i}>
                   {item.size.toUpperCase()} (OUT OF STOCK)
               </option>
           }
       })}
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

I enable or disable the option depending on qty field. The reason I pass value as an object is that multiple changes can happen:
[image]
[image]

In a picture you can see barcode change rendered successfully from `21METAHTAM29RL` to `21METAHTAM29RM` but not the size.

In similar threads I saw that `defaultValue` can be used instead of `value` in `Select` component and that would actually reflect the change, but it comes with all sorts of other problems. Specifically when I pick another product the filter i use to set the value to product that has qty higher than 0 won't work:

```
useEffect(()=>{
   setNewProd(product)
   if(product.length > 0){
      for(var i = 0; i < product[0].sizepricesdiscountqty.length; i++){
         if(parseInt(product[0].sizepricesdiscountqty[i].qty) > 0){
            setProdDetails(product[0].sizepricesdiscountqty[i])
            break;
         }
      }
   }
},[product])
```

It won't respect the filtering and the `defaultValue` will not show the product that was actually set.
Using `value` instead of `defaultValue` will respect the filtering and set the first product that has `qty` higher than 0.

I don't quite understand how are defaultValue and value different from each other. I tried using them both at the same time, but the change would not reflect either.
I don't know how to make Select component rerender successfully on change and respecting the filtering. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please create a sandbox for it? It will help to comprehend your problem and will also help to get to answer quickly.

Comment: After trial and fail I simply decided not to display Items with qty < 1. As for the problem I tried using inputProps per material-ui documentation and it did reflect the change in value, but ultimately didn't solve the problem with not displaying items with qty < 1.